# spring boot tomcat access logs log4j2 elastic common schema

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, log4j2, elastic-stack

Configuring spring boot to use log4j2 and the ECS was simple enough. All we needed to do was include the following dependencies in our pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>co.elastic.logging</groupId>
  <artifactId>log4j2-ecs-layout</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Then in the log4j2.xml file we just needed to include something like this:

```
<Console name="prod" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
  <EcsLayout serviceName="${service-name}" stackTraceAsArray="true" includeOrigin="true" includeMarkers="true" />
</Console>
```

However, when we configure spring boot to log the application access logs in application.yml we do this:

```
server:
  tomcat:
    accesslog:
      enabled: true
      encoding: UTF-8
      directory: /dev
      prefix: stdout
      buffered: false
      suffix:
      file-date-format:
      pattern: "ACCESS_LOG: %h %l %u \"%{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}t\" \"%r\" status=%s size=%b \"user-agent=%{User-Agent}i\""
```

The access logs are not logged as json with the EcsLayout.

How can I configure a spring boot application to log tomcat access logs as json to the console using the elastic common schema (json) format?

Comment: Did you get a solution for this issue?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.

Comment: Did you try using the [JsonTemplateLayout](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/json-template-layout.html) of log4j2 with `classpath:EcsLayout.json`?

Comment: @PabasaraMahindapala can you expand on your comment? If you know how to get this working and provide an example as an answer, and it works, I'll except it.

Comment: @axiopisty Added as an answer

Answer (score 1):

log4j2 has introduced the [JsonTemplateLayout](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/json-template-layout.html), which encodes LogEvents according to a structure described by a provided JSON template. They have support for the Elastic Common Schema (ECS) layout  as well (accessible via classpath:EcsLayout.json). You are able to add custom fields to the output as well using this approach as shown in their documentation.

Add the dependency to your pom.xml file

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-layout-template-json</artifactId>
    <version>2.20.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Configure the log4j2.xml file as shown

```
<Console name="prod" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
  <JsonTemplateLayout eventTemplateUri="classpath:EcsLayout.json"/>
</Console>
```

Now you should be able to see JSON output in the ECS layout in your console.

Comment: Upvoted because this is useful information. However, the pattern specified in the OP in the application.yml file "server.tomcat.accesslog.pattern" that configures tomcat access logs still does not print logs in the ECS format. This configuration enables my application logs to appear in EcsLayout format, but the tomcat server access logs still do not use EcsLayout.

Comment: @axiopisty Well we had a requirement at WSO2 to configure the tomcat HTTP access logs through log4j and it was achieved through a tomcat valve. Not sure if it would be helpful but here's the [PR](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-kernel/pull/2661).

Comment: @Parabasara Mahindapala, I just looked at your project. WSO2 looks like a very interesting project. I'm glad to have learned about it by looking at the PR you referenced. Thank you.